# Blurry Background Image SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a .jpeg image that I want as my background image for my SharePoint site. When I go to Change the Look I drop the image in, but it appears grainy/blurry and not clear when I save it to my site.

Here are the specs on the image I am using:
1024 X 683 pixels
Horizontal resolution 72dpi
Vertical resolution 72dpi

I have tried re-sizing the image to smaller, but get the same results.

Comment: dpi is for printers and has nothing to do with screenpixels:  
[The 72 ppi web resolution myth](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/essentials/the-72-ppi-web-resolution-myth/)

Answer (score 1):

SPO employs a semi-transparent overlay on your background to make content more visible.

You can increase the visibility of your background by reducing the alpha value using css. The overlay class is `ms-core-overlay`.

Try embedding the following code in using script or content editor

`<style>
.ms-core-overlay {
    background-color:rgba( 255,255,255,0.60);
</style>
}`

This reduces the overlay from 85% (it's default value) to 60%.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this JavaScript which will find the `img` tags inside the default SharePoint tags, will help you to change the `S Thumb` images to `L Thumb` or `M Thumb` images.

Map this JavaScript to master page.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.ms-profilepicture img').each(function () { 
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('SThumb.jpg', 'LThumb.jpg')); 
    }) 

     $('.ms-peopleux-userImgDiv img').each(function () { 
         $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('SThumb.jpg', 'LThumb.jpg')); 
    })
});
```

Hope it works for you.